# Spring ConversionService Lazy Load

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, converters

I have a Converter that transforms a domain object to a data transfer object. My domain object has a collection that is lazily loaded. If I don't put a `@Transactional` on the controller method using the conversion service I get `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`.

I also can't place `@Transactional` on the method or class in the Converter because it leads to

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to the determine sourceType <S> and targetType <T> which your Converter<S, T> converts between; declare these generic types.
```

So I was wondering what options do I have to fix this or a better design alternative?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to pass a fully internalized object .

Either mark your collection as `FetchType.EAGER`.

Or in your service itself, while retrieving,

```
hibernate.initialize(parent.getChilds())
```

Comment: Using `hibernate.initialize(parent.getChilds()) ` throws `org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session`

Comment: @Hank this means session is not present, try using first option `FetchType.EAGER`

Comment: Is there any alternative if I didn't want to Eager fetch it?